# Content security policy allow all

Tags: meta, content-security-policy, storybook

What can I do to prevent this error from occurring? I've already tried the following

```
default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: blob:;
```

But I keep getting the following error

> Refused to connect to 'https://storybook.js.org/versions.json?current=5.0.11' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

I tried to specify the URL directly or specified connect-src. But I just can't get it to work :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' storybook.js.org data: blob:;
```

Answer (score -1):

With "default-src *" you would allow pretty much any URL, the rest of you CSP doesn't change anything for a connect.

Are you sure you are not setting multiple CSP values? 
Is there a "default-src 'self'" meta tag or header?

If you have specified multiple CSPs the strict combination of all would be enforced.

Comment: That is the only one. Nothing is sent in the response header. Only the meta tag is defined


<meta
  http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
  content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: blob:;"
/>